# Error while computing Confusion matrix - Neuralnet package

Tags: r, neural-network, confusion-matrix

Data Used (sample):

```
EMpn Target Dailyrate DfrmHom   Empnumber   Target  Dailyrate   DFrmHome    Education   Employeecount   Age HourlyRate  Jobinvolvment   Joblevel
1   0   1   1   1   -1  1   1   1   1
2   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
3   0   1   -1  1   1   -1  1   1   1
4   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
5   0   1   -1  1   1   -1  1   1   1
6   1   1   -1  1   1   -1  1   -1  1
7   0   1   1   1   -1  1   1   1   1
8   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
9   1   1   -1  1   1   -1  1   1   1
10  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
11  0   1   -1  1   -1  -1  1   1   1
12  0   1   1   1   -1  1   1   1   1
13  0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
14  1   1   1   1   1   -1  1   1   1
15  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
16  1   1   -1  1   1   -1  1   -1  1
17  0   1   1   1   1   -1  1   1   1
18  0   1   -1  1   1   -1  1   1   1
19  0   1   1   1   -1  1   1   1   1
20  0   1   -1  1   1   -1  1   1   1
21  0   1   1   1   -1  1   1   1   1
22  0   1   1   1   -1  1   1   1   1
```

R code:

```
library(NeuralNetTools)
#Read the data for train and test data 
CTDF = read.csv("Project-Attrition.csv",header=T,na.strings=c(""))
# Let us set differnt seeds and extract 70 % of Poulation for arriving       
at  Development, Test and Holdout samples
CTDF.dev  = sample.split(CTDF$Target,SplitRatio=0.70)
head(split,20)
CTDF.train= subset(CTDF, split== TRUE)
str(CTDF.train)
View(CTDF.train)
table(CTDF.train$Target)
CTDF.test= subset(CTDF, split== FALSE)
str(CTDF.test)
table(CTDF.test$Target)
CTDF.NND=CTDF.train
CTDF.NNT=CTDF.test
Model = =nnet(Target~Dailyrate+DFrmHome +
           +Education+Employeecount+Age+HourlyRate+Jobinvolvment+Joblevel, 
            data=CTDF.NND, size=30, rang= 0.1, decay = 5e-4 , maxit = 500)
    table(Actual=CTDF.NND$Target, Prediction=predict(Model, data=CTDF.NND))
    CTDF.NNT$predict.class = predict(Model, CTDF.NNT)   
    confusionMatrix(CTDF.NNT$predict.class, CTDF.NNT$Target)
```

Output:

```
  str(CTDF.train)
      'data.frame': 3167 obs. of  10 variables:
  $ Empnumber    : int  1 2 4 5 6 7 11 12 14 15 ...
  $ Target       : int  0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 ...
  $ Dailyrate    : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  $ DFrmHome     : int  1 1 1 -1 -1 1 -1 1 1 1 ...
  $ Education    : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  $ Employeecount: int  -1 1 1 1 1 -1 -1 -1 1 1 ...
  $ Age          : int  1 1 1 -1 -1 1 -1 1 -1 1 ...
  $ HourlyRate   : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  $ Jobinvolvment: int  1 1 1 1 -1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  $ Joblevel     : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

For `table(Actual=CTDF.NND$Target, Prediction=predict(Model, data=CTDF.NND))` I was expecting a confusion matrix like below.

```
    0    1 
 0 
 1
```

However what I have got is :

```
       Prediction
Actual 0.00892725347390036 0.0358546806229366 0.0376897872686173 0.10518235583921 0.124456456913317
     0                   3                242                  1               34               197
     1                   0                  9                  0                4                28
      Prediction
Actual 0.1363541434416 0.236290782608584 0.286744920923175 0.331511427682813 0.613818492677834 0.726882504157994
     0              19                42                 5               474                51                 6
     1               3                13                 2               235                81                16
      Prediction
```

Also for test data for computing the confusion matrix I am getting the following errors:

```
   confusionMatrix(CTDF.NNT$predict.class, CTDF.NNT$Target)
```

> Error in confusionMatrix.default(CTDF.NNT$predict.class, CTDF.NNT$Target) :
> the data cannot have more levels than the reference

Please help in overcoming these issues.

Comment: Can you please improve formatting? Use the preview window to check your progress. Code snippets are not for R and I would recommend avoiding them.

Comment: I see only formatting issues for Prediction. Do you want me to update this portion alone ? Also code snippets are for "R" code only. Not sure why you think otherwise ?